# Plotly js chart hover text not displaying correct number values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

I am using plotly to show revenue in my chart, but the hover is not displaying the numbers correctly. Is there a way to fix this? when I hover on that value it should show something like 10714.78. Right now it is in an integer format. But even if i format to a string such as '10,714.78' it still does not behave properly. Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: The numbers **are** correct, they're simply using SI prefixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the numbers are technically correct as Gerardo Furtado pointed out, you can overwrite the output format via [`hoverformat`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-yaxis-hoverformat) which uses the [D3 formatting options](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format).

```js
var data = [{
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: ['10714.18', '12300', '30000'],
  type: 'bar',
  hoverinfo: "y"
}]
var layout = {
  hovermode: 'closest',
  yaxis: {
    hoverformat: ','
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
```